# What is a very descriptive and easy to understand description between git fetch and git pull? When is it better to git fetch vs git pull?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I am somewhat new to git any advice would be appreciated. Even a link to learn a more in depth free video/course practice could be useful to me here.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch/292359#292359

Answer (score 2):

**git fetch**

- Pulls code from the remote repository into your 'remote tracking branch'. Basically this means that information on any changes that have been commited to the remote repo is brought down to your local branch, but those changes aren't merged with your local copy of the branch, so the changes are *ready* to be merged. A fetch can be safely done without changing your own working copy of code in your local repository.

**git pull**

- Pulls down the code from the remote, the same as fetch, but *immediately merges* into your local branch, altering your local copy.

Use fetch whenever you want to bring down a *record* of the changes that have been made to the remote repository. For eg, you may just want local visibility of a new branch that's been created on the remote. Use pull when you want to merge all of the latest changes and immediately have them reflected in your branch.

Comment: thanks I really like your answer

Answer (score 1):

"In the simplest terms, git pull does a git fetch followed by a git merge."

Look here for some good info on it: [What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)